# When to use $ and when not to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have selected a control using the following variable

```
var txt = $("#text1");
```

Now when I have to handle events on the textbox, do I have to reference it as $(txt) or txt will do

```
$(txt).keydown(function() {})
```

or

```
txt.keydown(function(){})
```

What is the advantage. Please explain it taking the variable txt as the context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If txt is already equal to a jquery object, there is no need to use $(txt) as it's just extra processing to return the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is to declare your variables so know what they are.  Basically, what I'm saying is apply some [apps hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) and prefix your jQuery variables with a $

```
var $text1 = $("#text1");  // this is a jQuery object
var text1 = $text1[0];     // this is not
```

Comment: If a framework requires that you have to evolve practices like these, it's deeply disturbing.

Comment: @Rakesh - first of all, nobody is insinuating that it's *required*.  Secondly, I suspect you've never worked with large amounts of jQuery otherwise you'd know how intensely useful this simple convention is.  Remember, Apps Hungarian is the *good* type of Hungarian Notation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more info on Chad's response.

The `$()` is a short cut to the commonly used function 
`document.getElementById()`.

Once you lookup and store the object's value you don't need to look it up again. As Chad mentioned. Ask your self is the variable an object or a name (string), if it's a name you will have to lookup the object.

Comment: You are incorrect.  From the OP's example code, it's clear that he's using jQuery, in which case `$(…)` is jQuery's "dollar function": http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've found that using $(txt) yields more predictable results compared to assigning it as a reference ans using the reference to call the same methods/properties. It's possibly superstition on my part, however a few of us at work have been foiled by using a reference such as txt rather than an implicit $(txt) once txt has been assigned.